# Reversing an Animation

Tags: android, animation

I have an ImageView that gets animated when it is added to a layout.
When it is removed, I want to reverse the same animation.

Is there a way to reverse an animation in android without recoding it and reversing the parameters?

Comment: I do not think there's such a thing as `ReverseInterpolator`? Are you referring to `myAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);`?

Comment: change currect answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67635597/4797289

Answer (score 79, accepted):

No, sadly you cannot do it with the Animation object.
But you can simulate it using an interpolator that will inverse the animation:

```
package com.example.android;

import android.view.animation.Interpolator;

public class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float paramFloat) {
        return Math.abs(paramFloat -1f);
    }
}
```

Then on your animation you can set your new interpolator:

```
myAnimation.setInterpolator(new ReverseInterpolator());
```

Comment: I know I am late. I tried this code it is not working for me.After animation ends it just goes back to the start position without any animation. How can I animate in reverse?

Comment: Hello, I tried the code before posting it and it is working for me on a simple test. Please post some code showing how do you tried to apply the interpolator.

Comment: In some cases this may be a solution:                         animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

Comment: This can just be `return 1f - paramFloat;` because you're mapping `[0..1]` to `[1..0]`

Answer (score 29):

If you are using Object or ValueAnimator to animate the view, you can simply do

```
ValueAnimator myAnimator = new ValueAnimator();  
myAnimator.reverse()
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html).

Comment: This is only API level +23

Comment: The `ValueAnimator` class was added with the Animation API, which was introduced in API 11.

Answer (score 17):

Based on [pcans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259995/1129332) idea, you can reverse any interpolator, not just linear.

```
class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator{
    private final Interpolator delegate;

    public ReverseInterpolator(Interpolator delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public ReverseInterpolator(){
        this(new LinearInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        return 1 - delegate.getInterpolation(input);
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
ReverseInterpolator reverseInterpolator = new ReverseInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
myAnimation.setInterpolator(reverseInterpolator);
```

Comment: This wasn't working for me until I changed from `return 1 - delegate.getInterpolation(input);` to `return delegate.getInterpolation(1 - input);`.

Comment: Interesting. I guess it will work in all the symmetric delegates.

Answer (score 7):

I have a similar approach to **pcans** buts slightly different. It takes an `Interpolator` and will effectively pass out values that would be the same as using the passed in `Interpolator` normally and then in REVERSE mode. Saves you having to think about the buggy implementations of `Animation.REVERSE` across Android. See the code [here](https://github.com/doridori/AndroidUtilDump/blob/master/android/AndroidUtilDump/src/couk/doridori/android/lib/view/anim/ReverseInterpolator.java)

```
public class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator {

    private final Interpolator mInterpolator;

    public ReverseInterpolator(Interpolator interpolator){
        mInterpolator = interpolator;
    }

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        return mInterpolator.getInterpolation(reverseInput(input));
    }

    /**
     * Map value so 0-0.5 = 0-1 and 0.5-1 = 1-0
     */
    private float reverseInput(float input){        
        if(input <= 0.5)
            return input*2;
        else
            return Math.abs(input-1)*2;        
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! And solution from @pcans - didn't

Answer (score 6):

Simplest solution i came up with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toAlpha="1.0">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

Comment: android:repeatMode="reverse" saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the code remember the original position and the end position. And let your code dynamically get those values when triggering animation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RepeatCount and RepeatMode

**kotlin**

```
   var anim = TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 100)
   anim.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE // you cant 1,2,...
   anim.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE // you can set REVERSE or RESTART
   anim.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using animation from xml then an easy way is to made an exact same reverse animation to original animation. Add `Animation.AnimationListener` to original animation and in `onAnimationEnd` method start the reverse animation.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
 ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageViewUpb, "rotation", rotationAngle, rotationAngle + 180);

            if (linearLayoutb.getVisibility()==GONE){

                linearLayoutb.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.start();
                rotationAngle += 180;
                rotationAngle = rotationAngle%360;
        imageViewUpb.animate().rotation(rotationAngle).setDuration(500).start();

            }else{

                linearLayoutb.setVisibility(GONE);
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.start();
                rotationAngle += 180;
                rotationAngle = rotationAngle%180;
imageViewUpDownb.animate().rotation(rotationAngle).setDuration(500).start();

            }
```

linearlayoutb is the view that expands when the imageviewUpb faces up

make     `int rotationAngle = 0; global parameter`

Answer (score 0):

Since other answers have already been answered in Java, I will answer in **Kotlin**

---

```
// code inside onViewCreated()
...
        var anim: TranslateAnimation = TranslateAnimation(0F,60F,0F, 0F)
        anim.duration = 3000
        anim.fillAfter = true
        anim.repeatCount = -1
        anim.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE // back and forth
        binding.asteroid.startAnimation(anim)
...
```

---

This is the simplest approach in Kotlin.