# ViewAnimator black screen in Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a problem, I'm trying to make child in ViewAnimator, which will slide from bottom. And after back press, it will slide down again.

```
Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f
);
anim.setDuration(350);
anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

viewFlipper.setInAnimation(anim);
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(null);
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
```

onBackPress:

```
Animation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f
);
        anim.setDuration(350);
        anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(null);
        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(anim);
        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
```

But my problem is that when I click on button the first time, the **Screen goes black** and Child slides up. When I click on back button, everything is ok. (child slides down and behind is first screen...

Any help?

EDIT:

```
Animation inAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f
);
anim.setDuration(350);
anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

Animation outAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f
);
outAnim.setDuration(350);
outAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

viewFlipper.setInAnimation(inAnim);
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(outAnim);
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Animation inAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f
);
anim.setDuration(350);
anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

Animation outAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f
);
outAnim.setDuration(350);
outAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

viewFlipper.setInAnimation(inAnim);
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(outAnim);
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(null);
```

and

```
 viewFlipper.setInAnimation(null);
```

Essentially it tells the framework to HIDE the first view, and then animate the second one.

You **have** to supply the opposite direction animation.
This can be achieved using just **two** animations. Simply use the slide in and slide out for showing next view, and the same two animation for the opposite, but you have to **reverse** them - preferably by using some setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE) - refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120824/android-reversing-an-animation) or just declare additional reversed animations.

Comment: I don't know if you understand my expectation, but I want to have one child fixed in place, and second that will slide up and down.

Comment: Try to anim.setFillBefore(true) or anim.setFillAfter(true) for different result.