# Android undo view animation

Tags: android

I'm rotating an `ImageView` called `photo` with this code:

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(fromDegrees, toDegrees, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(400);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    });
    photo.startAnimation(rotate);
```

It rotates nicely and persists. Later I might want to change the picture in this ImageView. However, my new image appears rotated because of the persisted animation on the previous one. How can I "undo" this animation before switching images?

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120824/android-reversing-an-animation

Comment: Try to do the reverse animation and perhaps set the duration to 0 if you don't want it animated...

Comment: stopAnimation() not working?

Comment: stopAnimation() would not work as the animation finished a long time ago. So far the only viable solution is creating a reverse animation with 0 duration, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the best way to do this is with another animation with zero duration. If I have my original animation in this function:

```
private void rotatePhoto(int fromDegrees, int toDegrees, int duration) {
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(fromDegrees, toDegrees, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(duration);
    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    });
    photo.startAnimation(rotate);
}
```

I can rotate my photo 90 degrees with something like this: `rotatePhoto(0,90,400)`. Afterwards, to "undo" the animation, I can just use `rotatePhoto(0,0,0)`