# Reverse AnimatorSet

Tags: android, objectanimator

Is there a way to run an `AnimatorSet` in reverse on Android? The `ValueAnimator` API does provide a reverse method on the individual animators but not on a set of animators.

Comment: Just a quick thought, not tested or validated: You could probably use a custom `Interpolator` that runs backwards, i.e. returns something like `1.0 - input`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#setInterpolator%28android.animation.TimeInterpolator%29

Comment: you could use `getChildAnimations()` and reverse the collection, and add it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `AnimatorSet` is being played sequentially then you could use the method mentioned by @blackbelt:

```java
public static AnimatorSet reverseSequentialAnimatorSet(AnimatorSet animatorSet) {
    ArrayList<Animator> animators = animatorSet.getChildAnimations();
    Collections.reverse(animators);

    AnimatorSet reversedAnimatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    reversedAnimatorSet.playSequentially(animators);
    reversedAnimatorSet.setDuration(animatorSet.getDuration());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        // getInterpolator() requires API 18
        reversedAnimatorSet.setInterpolator(animatorSet.getInterpolator());
    }
    return reversedAnimatorSet;
}
```

The caveat being that this only works for simple sequential animations as any dependencies setup in the original `AnimatorSet` will be lost. Also, if an interpolator was used on the `AnimatorSet` it will only carry over on API 18 or newer (per method mentioned above, you could alternatively manually add the interpolator back to the new reversed animator set).

The individual animations within the `AnimatorSet` will not play in reverse, if that is desirable then you'll also have to iterate over the animations of the `AnimatorSet` and set a `ReverseInterpolator` on each, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28459276/196486) to [Android: Reversing an Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120824/android-reversing-an-animation).

Answer (score 1):

You can take the initial input values from i.e `ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1)` and switch them around with `yourAnimator.setFloatValues(1, 0)` before calling `yourAnimatorSet.start()` when you want to reverse animation

Answer (score 1):

The [reverse()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#reverse()) method has been added in API 26:

> Plays the AnimatorSet in reverse. If the animation has been seeked to a specific play time using setCurrentPlayTime(long), it will play backwards from the point seeked when reverse was called. Otherwise, then it will start from the end and play backwards. This behavior is only set for the current animation; future playing of the animation will use the default behavior of playing forward.
>
> Note: reverse is not supported for infinite AnimatorSet.