# How to do reverse animation from the animated position in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to animate the image using scale and rotate properties. I am able to start the animation. But how to do the reverse one from the animated position instead of the actual position of the image.

```
AnimatorSet animation = new AnimatorSet();
private void rotateImage(boolean isReverse) {
        if(isReverse){
            animation.playTogether(
                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fingerPrintImage, "rotation", 0, 60),
                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fingerPrintImage, "scaleX", 1, 0.5f),
                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fingerPrintImage, "scaleY", 1, 0.5f)
            );
        }
       else {
            animation.playTogether(
                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fingerPrintImage, "rotation", 0, 60),
                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fingerPrintImage, "scaleX", 1, 1.3f),
                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fingerPrintImage, "scaleY", 1, 1.3f)
            );
        }
        animation.setDuration(5000);
        animation.start();
    }

rotateImage(true);
```

Comment: I think you can reverse `AnimationSet` . Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025396/reverse-animatorset) . I am not sure but Give it a try anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually reversing your 'from' and 'to' float parameters f.e. :

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fingerPrintImage, "scaleX", 1, 1.3f) // forward

ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fingerPrintImage, "scaleX", 1.3f, 1) //backward
```

gives you an backward effect.

For animations like this, I strongly recommend [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html). It is super concise and has less code, no need for AnimationSets (which are often buggy), and you can chain different animations in one line :

```
private void rotateImage(boolean isReverse) {
    if(isReverse){
       fingerPrintImage.animate().rotationBy(-60).scaleXBy(0.3f).scaleYBy(0.3f).setDuration(5000);
    } else {
       fingerPrintImage.animate().rotationBy(60).scaleXBy(-0.3f).scaleYBy(-0.3f).setDuration(5000);
}
```

Maybe you have to tweak your values a bit, but this should be all you need.

Even shorter and more dynamic would be passing all float values through function parameters :

```
private void rotateImage(View view, float rotate, float scaleY, float scaleX, long duration) {
    view.animate().rotationBy(rotate).scaleXBy(scaleX).scaleYBy(scaleY).setDuration(duration);
}
```

which then can be called like :

```
rotateImage(fingerPrintImage, 60, 0.3f, 0,3f, 5000); // forward
rotateImage(fingerPrintImage, 60, -0.3f, -0.3f, 5000) //backwards
```

this minimizes code, gets rid of the isReverse boolean, and you are also able to reuse the method with different parameters for further animations.

Comment: Thanks mate! It's elegant.

Comment: How to stop and set back to the original while in transition?

Comment: assuming you want to cancel on click, in your onClick() you can cancel the animation with the cancel() method, then use the .setListener() method (both ViewPropertyAnimator) and override the onAnimationCancel() method, in which you then can animate back to the original position.