# Android adding custom Interpolator to Animation prevents the animation from getting cancel

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

I have extended the Animation class to show circle being drawn as animation here is my Animation class

```
public class CircleAnimation extends Animation {

    private Circle circle;

    private float oldAngle;
    private float newAngle;

    public CircleAnimation(Circle circle, int newAngle) {
        this.oldAngle = circle.getAngle();
        this.newAngle = newAngle;
        this.circle = circle;
        setInterpolator(new ReverseInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation) {
        float angle = oldAngle + ((newAngle - oldAngle) * interpolatedTime);
        circle.setAngle(angle);
        circle.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected and now I wanted to reverse the animation i.e start from a full circle to half circle and finally to empty.
The easiest way I found was to use a custom Interpolator as described here in the stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120824/reversing-an-animation) and I implemented the same.

```
public class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float paramFloat) {
        return Math.abs(paramFloat - 1f);
    }
}
```

I have two button to start and stop the animation

```
    public void stop(View v) {
        if (circle != null) {
            circle.getAnimation().cancel();
        }
    }

    public void start(View v) {
        CircleAnimation animation = new CircleAnimation(circle, 360);
        animation.setDuration(10000);
        circle.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

The problem is if I use the **setInterpolator(new ReverseInterpolator());** in my animation to reverse the circle being drawn the start and stop works only once and if I try starting it again the animation does not work but if I remove the **ReverseInterpolator** from my animation to draw circle the start and stop works any number of time, Can someone explain why is this happening?